# Data is not storing into database from the controller in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.4

here is the route code

```
Route::resource('/catalog', 'CatalogController');
```

CatalogController.php

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request,[
        'cat_name'=>'required',
        'cat_desc'=>'required',
        'short_name'=>'required|min:0|integer',
        'category_image'=>'required'
    ]);
    $categories=new Category;

    $title=$request->get('cat_name');
    $desc=$request->get('cat_desc');
    $short_name=$request->get('short_name');
    $categories['cat_name']=$title;
    $categories['cat_desc']=$desc;
    $categories['short_name']=$short_name;

    if($request->file('image')){
        $file=$request->file('image');
        $imgname=$file->getClientOriginalName();
        $file->move('images',$imgname);
    }

    $categories['category_image']=$imgname;
    $categories->save();
    return redirect('/catalog');

}
```

Is there any problem in the Controller code? There is no problem in getting the data and I have already checked them by returning each of the lines. But every time I try to insert data, it returns to same create page.

and this is the code of create.blade.php

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-20">
    <h2 style="color: lightslategrey; padding-left: 30px;">Create Category</h2>

    {!!Form::open(['method'=>'POST', 'action'=>'CatalogController@store','files'=>true ])!!}
        {{ csrf_field() }}

                <div class="form-group row" style="padding-left: 60px; padding-top: 30px; width: 1350px;">
                    <label for="cat_name" class="col-2 col-form-label">Category Title :</label>
                    <input class="form-control" name ="cat_name" type="text" placeholder="Enter Title" required>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row" style="padding-left: 60px; padding-top: 10px; width: 1350px;">
                    <label for="cat_desc" class="col-2 col-form-label">Category Description :</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" name ="cat_desc" rows= "3" type="text" placeholder="Enter Description" required></textarea>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row" style="padding-left: 60px; padding-top: 10px; width: 1350px;">
                    <label for="short_name" class="col-2 col-form-label">Short Name</label>
                    <input  class="form-control" name ="short_name" type="text" placeholder="Enter Short Name" required>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row" style="padding-left: 60px; padding-top: 10px; width: 1350px;">
                    <label for="image" class="col-2 col-form-label">Upload Image:</label>
                    <input class="form-control" name ="image" type="file" placeholder="Choose a Image" required>
                </div>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <div class="form-group ">
                    <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-5">
                        <button class = 'btn btn-success' type="submit" style="width: 200px;">Add Category</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
         {!! Form::close()  !!}
     </div>
</div>
```

I have no idea what is the problem. Same code is running in other controller. But this is not working.There is no problem with the database connection and models.

Comment: Redirecting back usually indicates a validation failure, you should check the `$errors` variable in your view. For example are you sure `short_name` is an integer? If so why don't you call it `short_number` ?

Comment: @apokryfos  short_name is a string. it is like a tag actually. there is no validating error.. because same code is running in another controller nicely.

Comment: `'short_name'=>'required|min:0|integer',` you are validating it as an integer. If it's not an integer then it will fail validation. If validation fails then the default action is to redirect back to the form with the `$errors` variable populated with validation errors and the `session()->old()` to be populated with the old input. You are not checking these in the code you shared

Comment: oh yes sorry. i have corrected it and refreshed. still not working

Comment: Is there anything in the `$errors` variable?

Comment: Also you're validating `'category_image'=>'required'` but the name in your form is `image`

Comment: thank you so much @apokryfos. it was a silly mistake. your last comment saved me :D

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying to use the model as array but its an object so the arrow notation is the right way to go. (https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#retrieving-models)

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request,[
        'cat_name'=>'required',
        'cat_desc'=>'required',
        'short_name'=>'required|min:0|integer',
        'category_image'=>'required'
    ]);

    $category = new Category;
    $category->cat_name = $request->get('cat_name');
    $category->cat_desc = $request->get('cat_desc');
    $category->short_name = $request->get('short_name');


    $file = $request->file('image');
    $imageName = $file->getClientOriginalName();
    $file->move('images', $imgname);
    $category->category_image = $imageName;
    $category->save();

    return redirect('/catalog');
}
```

I've updated your snippet for you and also simplified it a little bit. You should be more precise with your variable-namings e.g. $categories (in your code) just represents a category. Processing the image does not have to be done inside a condition-statement if present as you declared it as required in validation.

Comment: Eloquent models implement the `ArrayAccess` interface so `$categories["something"]=$value` should do the exact same thing as `$categories->something=$value` since they're both implemented to alias `setAttribute("something",$value)`